# WebDriverException Error

Tags: python, selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running a script to collect information from various pages on a website.

```
#python2
from __future__ import division

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from BeautifulSoup import SoupStrainer
import pandas as pd
import urllib,re,csv,os,urllib2,requests,itertools,pdfkit,time
import smtplib
import math
from selenium import webdriver
import requests.packages.urllib3
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from datetime import datetime
os.environ["LANG"] = "en_US.UTF-8"


start_time = time.time()

os.chdir('DIRECTORY')


#import .csv with variables for fulls list

fulls = zip(orgs, terms, sites, smo_ids, year_i, year_start, year_end)

orgs2 = []
terms2 = []
sites2 = []
results2 = []
smo_ids2 = []
article_number = []
years2 = []

numbers = range(2000001)
numbers = numbers[0::200]

start_time = time.time()

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1600, 1200))
display.start()

otime = datetime.now()

startpoint = 1
for full in fulls:
    site = full[2]
    org = full[0]
    smo_id = full[3]
    term = full[1]
    year = full[4]
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
    try:
        driver.get(site) #get original site info
    except (WebDriverException, TimeoutException) as e:
        print(e.Message)
        print "REFRESHING PAGE"
        driver.refresh(site)
    source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
    soup2 = soup.encode("utf-8")
    try:
        resultno = re.findall('<h1 id="pqResultsCount">\n(.*?) result',soup2)
        resultno = ''.join(resultno)
        resultno = resultno.translate(None, "(){}<>,")
        resultno = int(resultno)
    except ValueError, e:
        resultno = int(0)
    no_pages = int(math.ceil(resultno/20))
    an = re.findall('{"(.*?)markedlistcheckbox:markallitems',soup2)
    an = ''.join(an)
    an = re.findall('markAll":false,"formats":{(.*?)},"markURL"',an)
    an = ''.join(an)
    an = re.sub(r'":.+?,"', '', an)
    an = an.translate(None, '"')
    an = an.split(':', 1)[0]
    an = an.split('MSTAR_')
    an.pop(0)
    for i in an:
        article_number.append(i)
        years2.append(year)
        sites2.append(site)
        orgs2.append(org)
        smo_ids2.append(smo_id)
        terms2.append(term)
    #begin encryption search
    encrypt = re.findall('id="searchForm"(.*?)/></div>',soup2)
    encrypt = ''.join(encrypt)
    encrypt
    t_ac = re.findall('name="t:ac" type="hidden" value="(.*?)/',encrypt)
    t_ac = ''.join(t_ac)
    t_ac
    t_formdata = re.findall('name="t:formdata" type="hidden" value="(.*?)"',encrypt)
    t_formdata = ''.join(t_formdata)
    t_formdata
    #start page 2 stuff
    for page in range(2,no_pages+1):
        site_ = "https://WEBSITE.com/results:gotopage/" + str(page) + "?t:ac=" + t_ac + "/?t:formdata=" + t_formdata + ""
        driver.get(site_) #get subsequent page info
        source = driver.page_source # Here is your populated data for the page source
        soup_ = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
        soup2_ = soup_.encode("utf-8")
        an_ = re.findall('{"(.*?)markedlistcheckbox:markallitems',soup2_)
        an_ = ''.join(an_)
        an_ = re.findall('markAll":false,"formats":{(.*?)},"markURL"',an_)
        an_ = ''.join(an_)
        an_ = re.sub(r'":.+?,"', '', an_)
        an_ = an_.translate(None, '"')
        an_ = an_.split(':', 1)[0]
        an_ = an_.split('MSTAR_')
        an_.pop(0)
        for i_ in an_:
            article_number.append(i_)
            years2.append(year)
            sites2.append(site)
            orgs2.append(org)
            smo_ids2.append(smo_id)
            terms2.append(term)
    driver.quit()
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    try:
        ctime_1 = ctime
    except:
        ctime_1 = otime
    m, s = divmod(elapsed_time, 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    ctime = datetime.now()
    diftime = ctime - ctime_1
    diftime = str(diftime)
    diftime = diftime[2:7]
    ctime2 = str(ctime)
    ctime2 = ctime2[11:19]
    print "%d:%02d:%02d  |  %s  |  %s" % (h, m, s, ctime2, diftime)
    print "%d: Page %d is complete" % (startpoint, startpoint)
    if startpoint in numbers:
        print "Sleeping for 10 seconds"
        time.sleep(10)
    startpoint += 1



article_info = zip(article_number, years2, sites2, orgs2, smo_ids2, terms2)
```

The code runs, but at various points (sometimes 20 mins into the run, sometimes 14 hours into it), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 131, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 151, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 240, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
(Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.186)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.13.0-36-generic x86_64)
```

I'm using current `chrome` and `chromedriver`, and I have tried this using `selenium` versions 3.9, 3.8, and 3.7. No matter what, I eventually get the above error.

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Comment: Your code trials and system _JDK_ version please.

Comment: 1. unsure of my JDK version. any idea how to pull that info?

Comment: Well, as you are using `Python` bindings `JDK` version won't have any major impact though but your code trial will help us to analyze the real issue.

Comment: added the code in the question above.